# How to get results based on time from BigQuery?

Tags: ios, sql, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've a requirement to fetch the data for a specific time frame. Currently, I can only fetch the data based on date. How do I fetch the data for the same date range but the time frame being 3-5PM?

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) as uniques,
  COUNT(user_pseudo_id) as total
FROM
  `XYZ.analytics_123.events_*`
WHERE
  app_info.install_source = "iTunes"   
  AND (Extract (DATE FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS( user_first_touch_timestamp )) between "2020-05-20" and 
        "2020-05-20")
  AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX between "20200520" AND "20200520")

GROUP BY
  event_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp )) BETWEEN 15 AND 17` as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  event_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS uniques,
  COUNT(user_pseudo_id) AS total
FROM `XYZ.analytics_123.events_*`
WHERE app_info.install_source = "iTunes"   
  AND (EXTRACT (DATE FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp )) BETWEEN "2020-05-20" AND "2020-05-20")
  AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20200520" AND "20200520")
  AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp )) BETWEEN 15 AND 17)
GROUP BY event_name
```